# How to return all combinations using outer joins on multiple tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have three tables 
X, Y and Z 
and 
I have joining tables between 
XY, YZ and XZ. 
Now I want to find all the combinations of X,Y and Z using join. I have used

```
select * from X 
left outer join XY 
on 
X.xid = XY.xID  
right outer join Y 
on 
XY.yID = Y.yID 
left outer join YZ 
on 
YZ.yid=y.yid 
right outer join Z 
on 
Z.zid=YZ.zid
```

However, this gives me a wrong set of data. Can anyone correct me where I'm going wrong? 
    X.   Y
    11.   22
    12.   Null
     Null 22
     Null. 13

Comment: For one, you're missing a join of XZ to Z and XZ to X.

Comment: are you actual using mysql & db2?  If not, please drop the one you're not using.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all combinations from each table, you can create a Cartesian product like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM x, y, z;
```

If you want to use the join syntax, you can use a [CROSS JOIN](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-cross-join.php):

```
SELECT *
FROM x
CROSS JOIN y
CROSS JOIN z;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f770f/2) example that shows both are the same.

Comment: So basically I have a connecting table XY between X and Y. Now I need to get a data set with all the x values no matter of they have corresponding y value or not and also all y values no matter if they have corresponding x values or not in the same table. I updated my question accordingly @McAdam331

Comment: @user3317862 Can you add some rows from each of the tables, or build an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) so I can better understand your problem?